# What is faster collection.Insert(0, newItem) vs list.Add(newItem) + Sort in Winforms ListView C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting

I have a ListView that I need to update by adding an item. Using `.Add()` will place it on the bottom. So I can then sort it by a insert time (it's one of the fields). Another option is to use `Collection.Insert(0, newItem)` that will put it to the top and move everything down one index.

Read somewhere that `Collection.Insert(0, newItem)` may be slow for larger lists b/c of the shifting. 
If that is the case - what would be faster? Collection or Add + Sort?

or is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: How many items are you adding?

Comment: Create a simple `Unit Test` that `Insert/Add`s thousands of items...

Comment: @Oded over the course of a session > 1000

Comment: In succession? How often? 1000, or even 10000 is not that much. You are not likely to see a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert will be faster than Add + Sort, because Sorting will involve unnecessary comparisons if your list is already sorted.  But like others have said, it probably won't matter enough to care.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have millions of items, it won't matter and you're simply pre-optimizing and either will be fine.  If you do have millions of items, then you are presenting to the user too many items.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is going to be displayed to a user, it's probably not going to be large enough for the performance difference to be noticeable. Probably use whichever makes more sense in the context.